# "Product" matching query does not exist, django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, postman

I encounter this error when testing the API to create order. The order gets created when I make the request still I get that
error message. The order has relatinship with the orderItem and orderItem has relationship with the product model  as shown in the models.py. How do i eliminate this error? The django code is valid because it is working on frontend but the issue seems to be in the way I structure the request body on postman as shown below:

```
{
    "orderItems":[{
        "product": 1,
        "qty":"2",
        "price":"200"
    }],
    "shippingAddress": {
        "address":"u-address", "city":"u-city", "postalCode":"12345", "country":"u-country"
    },
    
    "paymentMethod":"p-method",
    "itemPrice":"2000"
}
```

Here is the code of the model and the view.

```
'''
models.py
'''
class Product(models.Model):
    category = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=Categories.choices, default=Categories.medications)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name="user_product", null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    brand = models.CharField(max_length=255, default="brand")
    productClass = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="images/products/")
    label = models.CharField(max_length=254, default='', blank=True, null=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
    stock = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True, default=0)
    dateCreated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)


class Order(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name="user_order", null=True)
    paymentMethod = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    dateCreated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.dateCreated)


class OrderItem(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    image = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    qty = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True, default=0)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)
'''
views.py
'''
def addOrderItems(request):
    user = request.user
    data = request.data

    orderItems = data['orderItems']

    if orderItems and len(orderItems) == 0:
        return Response({'detail': 'Order item was not provided'}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
    else:

        # Step 1: Create order

        order = Order.objects.create(
            user=user,
            paymentMethod=data['paymentMethod'],
        )

        #Step 2: Create shipping address

        shipping = ShippingAddress.objects.create(
            order=order,
            address=data['shippingAddress']['address'],
        )

        # Step 3: Create order items, then set order to orderItem relationship
        for i in orderItems:
            product = Product.objects.get(id=i['product'])

            item = OrderItem.objects.create(
                product=product,
                order=order,
                name=product.name,
                qty=i['qty'],
                price=i['price'],
                image=product.image.url,
            )

                # Step 4: Update stock
            product.countInStock -= item.qty
            product.save()

        serializer = OrderSerializer(order, many=False)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: Can you add the error message here?

Comment: The error is `"Product" matching query does not exist, django` and it is coming from the the view because of the way I'm making the request on postman. It seems the json requires more details of the product to work. In the frontend I send the cartItems as the orderItems and everything works fine but here I'm trying to do something similar on postman but every effort I make fails

Comment: I think the error occurs on the line `product = Product.objects.get(id=i['product'])`. Does the product with id: 1 actually exist?

Comment: Thanks so much @David Lu. I don't really know how to express my thanks for your assistance. It's working now, the product with the id didn't exist that was the issue

Comment: Thanks. Could you please accept my answer of your previous question? I think my answer was correct.